# How can I get the active user before the rest of the client-side function runs in Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications

As it is, the function runs, the data set is built, but the user shows as `null` and that is probably because the client-side function continues running without waiting for the piece below to return the data.

```
const user = google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(user) {
console.log('User: ' + user);
}).getUser();
```

So, how can I make `savePO()` wait for the user returned, so that it builds the data set correctly?

```
function savePo() {
  const table = document.querySelectorAll("#tableRows tr")
  let tableData = [...table].map(r => {
    let td = r.querySelectorAll("td");
    return [...td].map((c, j) =>
      j == 9 ? c.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]')[0].checked :
      j == 8 ? c.innerText :
      c.querySelector('input').value)
  });

  let timeStamp = new Date();
  timeStamp = timeStamp.toString();
  const user = google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(user) {
  console.log('User: ' + user);
  }).getUser();
  const notes = document.getElementById('notes').value;

  tableData.forEach(function(row) {
    row.unshift(supplier, buyer, billTo, notes);
    headerData.forEach(function(el) {
      row.unshift(el);
    })
    row.push(timeStamp, user);
  })
  console.log('Complete Table Data: ' + JSON.stringify(tableData)) //Returs all, but user is null
}
```

Thanks!

PS: Don't mind how terrible it may look - best practice wise. Learning What first, then I'll improve How as I go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply move your google.script.run outside of savePo and call it from within the success handler callback function.  Let say `someEventHandler` is associated with a button on your HTML page.  Now `getUser()` is called first to get the `user`.  When it finishes it calls `savePo(user)`.

```
function someEventHandler() {
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(user) {
    savePo(user);
  }).getUser();
}

function savePo(user) {
  const table = document.querySelectorAll("#tableRows tr")
  let tableData = [...table].map(r => {
    let td = r.querySelectorAll("td");
    return [...td].map((c, j) =>
      j == 9 ? c.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]')[0].checked :
      j == 8 ? c.innerText :
      c.querySelector('input').value)
  });

  let timeStamp = new Date();
  timeStamp = timeStamp.toString();
  const notes = document.getElementById('notes').value;

  tableData.forEach(function(row) {
    row.unshift(supplier, buyer, billTo, notes);
    headerData.forEach(function(el) {
      row.unshift(el);
    })
    row.push(timeStamp, user);
  })
  console.log('Complete Table Data: ' + JSON.stringify(tableData)) //Returs all, but user is null
}
```

Comment: In my research, I also saw folks using promise, but this is still quite advanced to me and this will do it! Thanks a  lot once again!